# How to align a div centered without explicit size?

Tags: html, css

I want to align a `div` centered horizontally in the page. The div contains several html content like, images, links, texts etc.

For the sake of it I cannot use `display:table`, which would align the div in center. How could I else align the content, without having to give an explicit `width`?

Comment: are you just want horizontal alignment or vertical also?
if both then     *Flex* will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or without using flex, translate or absolute positioning:

```css
#container {
    text-align:center;
}

#center {
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="center">
        this is a test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `justify-content: center` in flexbox layout. No need of setting a width.

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <span class="text">Test text</span>
  <a href="#">Test link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: *most browsers?* Yes! Since it supports from IE10: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Be careful with compatibility, IE10 it's partial support, with -ms prefix and with old 2012 syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can center horizontally and vertically (as you like) with a translate so easy, and without know the width or the height:

```
 <div class="parent"> 
   <div class="center">
     Centered
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .parent { 
      position: relative; 
 }
 .center { 
      position: absolute; 
      left:50%; 
      transform: translateX(-50%); 
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); 
  }
```

To center vertically use translateY()

Snippet:

```css
     .parent { 
          position: relative; 
          width: 100%;
          height: 500px;
         border: 1px solid black;
     }
     .center { 
          height: 240px;
          position: absolute; 
          left:50%; 
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
          -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
      }
```

```html
     <div class="parent"> 
       <div class="center">
         Centered
       </div>
     </div>
```